# Counting occourences of a variable in an array filled with objects in JavaScript / Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filtering

Lets say i have an array filled with objects like this:

```
 {conversation_id: 38
  id: 99
  is_seen: 1 
  message: "Hej Kristina"
  timestamp: "2015-07-08T10:50:49.000Z"'
 }
```

Now I wish I could find out how many of these objects has the value `is_seen` set to `1` and `conversation_id` set to `38`.

I could solve this by using a `forEach` loop, however I am looking for a solution that is cleaner and maybe even more efficient.

My application is an `AngularJs application`, so I'm looking for either native `JavaScript` or `Angular` ways to solve this.

Comment: you could use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Something along the lines of:  `my_array.filter(function(el) { return el.conversation_id == 38 && is_seen == 1; }).length;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the native [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```js
var countOfSeenItems = my_array.filter(function (el) {
  return el.conversation_id == 38 && is_seen == 1; 
}).length;
```

Comment: Array.prototype.filter is not available in Internet Explorer before version 9 -  http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.filter

Comment: @phuzi what do you suggest for legacy then?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen there's a polyfill on MDN  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 3):

You can use angular js filter

```
  var seenObjects = $filter('filter')(itemsList, function(rule) {
     return rule.is_seen === 1 && rule.conversation_id === 38;
   });
console.log(seenObjects.length);
```

Comment: You forgot to check `conversation_id`.